# Is it possible to remove Relations column from generated xml

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xml-parsing, dataset

Hi I am creating my xml via below code

```
 DataSet ds = new DataSet("OrderDetail");
 DataTable Detail = new DataTable("Detail");
 DataTable Items = new DataTable("Items");

 string query = "Some Query";
 SqlDataAdapter dataAdapt = new SqlDataAdapter(query , conn);
 dataAdapt.Fill(Detail);
 ds.Tables.Add(Detail);

 string loopingquery = "Some Query";
 SqlDataAdapter dataAdapt1 = new SqlDataAdapter(loopingquery, conn);
 dataAdapt1.Fill(Items);
 ds.Tables.Add(Items);

 DataRelation relation = ds.Relations.Add("relation", ds.Tables["Detail"].Columns["OrderNumber"], ds.Tables["Items"].Columns["OrderNumber"]);
 relation.Nested = true;
 ds.WriteXml(Server.MapPath("~/") + Detail.Rows[0]["OrderNumber"] + "_XML.xml");
```

But I need to remove the ***OrderNumber column*** from  ***Items DataTable*** before generating the xml.

I had tried removing column as

```
ds.Tables["Items"].Columns.Remove("OrderNumber");
```

but it is giving exception as

> relational column can not be deleted.

**How Can I do So, Is it possible to hide the OrderNumber Column. Or is there any other way?**

XML Sample

```
<OrderDetail>
  <Detail>
    <OrderNumber>354699</OrderNumber>
    <OrderDate>01/09/2018</OrderDate>    
    <Items>
      <OrderNumber>354699</OrderNumber>   //Need to remove or hide
      <Quantity>1</Quantity>
      <Sku>test240</Sku>
      <Item>testEye®</Item>
      <Price>22.95</Price>
    </Items>
    <Items>
      <OrderNumber>354699</OrderNumber>   //Need to remove or hide
      <Quantity>1</Quantity>
      <Sku />
      <Item>test</Item>
      <Price>-32.95</Price>
    </Items>
  </Detail>
</OrderDetail>
```

**You Can choose any one method from below to remove nodes from XML**

**Issue Resolved update 1 for new version**

```
Using System.XML.Linq; (NameSpace)   

string xml = ds.GetXml();
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
doc.Descendants("OrderNumbers").Remove();
doc.Save(Server.MapPath("~/") + "XMLGeneration.xml");
```

**Issue Resolved update 2 For new and older version(2.0)**

```
Using System.XML; (NameSpace)   

string str = Convert.ToString(ds.GetXml());
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(str);
XmlNodeList nodes = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Items");
foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
      node.RemoveChild(node.SelectSingleNode("//OrderNumbers"));
}
xmlDoc.Save(Server.MapPath("~/") + "XMLGeneration.xml");
```

**Issue Resolved update 3 For new and older version(2.0)**

```
Using System.XML; (NameSpace)   

ds.WriteXml(Server.MapPath("~/") + "XMLGeneration.xml");
xmlDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/") + "XMLGeneration.xml");
XmlNodeList nodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//Items");
foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
    node.RemoveChild(node.SelectSingleNode("//OrderNumbers"));
}
xmlDoc.Save(Server.MapPath("~/") + "XMLGeneration.xml");
```

Comment: You could do what you are doing, then transform the xml the way you want it with Linq to XML or any XML API.

Comment: Can you give answer as brief, I am new for how to create and I am using ado.net code to get data in datatable

Comment: @Crowcoder Please check my update code to create the xml

Comment: Can you add a small sample of the xml you are getting and what it would look like the way you want it?

Comment: @Crowcoder I have update the question with sample xml, I need to remove the OrderNumber Commented as (//Need to remove or hide)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the xml from your DataSet and then do a second step to remove the OrderNumber elements. Make sure to add `using` for `System.Xml.Linq`.

```
string xml = "<OrderDetail><Detail><OrderNumber>354699</OrderNumber><OrderDate>01/09/2018</OrderDate>    <Items><OrderNumber>354699</OrderNumber><Quantity>1</Quantity><Sku>test240</Sku><Item>testEye®</Item><Price>22.95</Price></Items><Items><OrderNumber>354699</OrderNumber><Quantity>1</Quantity><Sku /><Item>test</Item><Price>-32.95</Price></Items></Detail></OrderDetail>";
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
doc.Descendants("OrderNumber").Remove();
doc.Save(Server.MapPath("~/") + ......);
```

Comment: What will be the namespace of XDocument? and you want me to do some thing like string xml = convert.tostring( ds.WriteXml);

Comment: `XDocument` is in `System.Xml.Linq`. You can use `ds.GetXml()` instead of `WriteXml()` to get the xml as a string.

Comment: I had downloaded System.Xml.Linq.dll from path https://www.dllme.com/dll/download/6428/System.Xml.Linq.dll still namespace of system.xml.linq is not calling

Comment: You don't need to download anything, it is included in the .Net framework. You should remove the reference for what you downloaded. If you type "System.Xml.Linq.XDocument. " you don't get any intellisense?

Comment: You should also scan your pc for Viruses now.

Comment: yes I do not get any intellisense. Do we have any other way?

Comment: I have only using System.Xml.Schema;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Xml.XmlConfiguration;
using System.Xml.XPath;
using System.Xml.Xsl;

Comment: What version of .Net are you using? I've never heard of anyone having problems using System.Xml.Linq

Comment: its 2.0 version, I have added dll in bin folder

Comment: That explains it. You can use `System.Xml` API instead but I don't have an example for that.

Comment: in that namespace it is `XmlDocument`, not `XDocument`. The code will be different, you cannot use my code example with `XmlDocument`.

Comment: Can u help me out?

Comment: Can you help me out using XmlDocument

Comment: I would have to look up how to use that API, I really don't ever use it. Did you upgrade the version of .Net framework so you could use XDocument?